# Crossmatrix comparison with purrr

Tags: r, matrix, comparison, purrr

I'm trying to compare each element list of objects with every other element with `purrr` with a cross matrix as a result.

To very much simplify the problem, say I want to compare the numbers 1, 2 and 3 with each other and check if they are the same. Currently, my approach ist this:

```r
library(purrr)
vec = 1:3

cross_matrix <- cross2(vec,vec) %>%
  map_lgl(function(x){x[[1]] == x[[2]]}) %>%
  matrix(nrow = length(vec))

cross_matrix
#>       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
#> [1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#> [2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#> [3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE



# remove redundant comparisons (diagonals excluded)
cross_matrix[lower.tri(cross_matrix,diag = F)] <- NA

cross_matrix
#>      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
#> [1,] TRUE FALSE FALSE
#> [2,]   NA  TRUE FALSE
#> [3,]   NA    NA  TRUE

# remove redundant comparisons (diagonals included)
cross_matrix[lower.tri(cross_matrix,diag = T)] <- NA

cross_matrix
#>      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
#> [1,]   NA FALSE FALSE
#> [2,]   NA    NA FALSE
#> [3,]   NA    NA    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

I have the following issues:

1. `map_lgl()` runs the calculations `1 == 2` *and* `2 == 1`, which can be a redundant operation. How can I omit this? The desired output would be a matrix as achieved by running `cross_matrix[lower.tri(cross_matrix,diag = F)] <- NA` (see code above)
2. Sometimes, running `1 == 1` and `2 == 2` does not make sense. How can I control this? The desired output would be a matrix as achieved by running `cross_matrix[lower.tri(cross_matrix,diag = T)] <- NA` (see code above)
3. is `cross2(vec,vec)` the right approach or is there a more elegant shorthand (the repetition seems a bit clumsy)

**EDIT**:

It is important that the redundant operations in questions 1 and 2 can be omitted *before* they are calculated to reduce computation time. Also, this is of course a oversimplified example: It would be great to have a solutions that takes silent functions, preferably with `purrr`.

Comment: 3) You might use `outer(vec, vec, '==')` to create `cross_matrix`

Comment: Or even `sapply(vec, "==", vec)`.

Comment: Maybe I wan't too clear specifying that the redundant operations should be removed before they are calculated to reduce computation time. Neither suggestions solves this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a `purrr` specific operation but completely base R operation using `combn`

```
cross_matrix <- function(vec) {
    vals <- combn(vec, 2, function(x) x[1] == x[2])
    mat <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(vec), ncol = length(vec))
    diag(mat) <- TRUE #depending on what value you want for diagonals
    mat[lower.tri(mat)] <- vals
    t(mat)
}

cross_matrix(1:3)
#     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
#[1,] TRUE FALSE FALSE
#[2,]   NA  TRUE FALSE
#[3,]   NA    NA  TRUE

cross_matrix(c(1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4))
#     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]
#[1,] TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#[2,]   NA  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[3,]   NA    NA  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[4,]   NA    NA    NA  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#[5,]   NA    NA    NA    NA  TRUE FALSE
#[6,]   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA  TRUE
```

Check output for

```
combn(1:3, 2)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    1    2
#[2,]    2    3    3
```

The operation are performed only for these 3 combinations and not for all 9 combination.

This takes care of your issue 1 and issue 2.

`1 == 2` and `2 == 1` are not recomputed and also no conparision is done with itself (`1 == 1` and `2 == 2`).